# R Shiny: how do i make the datatable display the last page on every reactive update?

Tags: r, shiny

How do I make the below always display the last page of the table instead of the first page on every reactive update ?

`output$myTable <- DT::renderDataTable(datatable(df) %>% formatRound(c(2:5),2))`

Note that reversing the order of the table is not what i wanted.

What I want is that when i start the app, it will bring me to the last page of the table always.

Answer (score 2):

### reverse order

Use order option to show table as "reverse" ordered.

https://rstudio.github.io/DT/options.html

---

### Edit : added page to last

I'm not sure difference about **reverse order** and **page to last**.

but page to last can be achieved by using `callback`.

refer these

- [page() API](https://datatables.net/reference/api/page())
- [Callback usage](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/) (2.9)

Here's minimal reproducible example.

```
library(DT)
datatable(
  data.frame(a = 1:50, b = 1:50 * 2),
  callback = JS(
    'table.page("last").draw(false);'
  )
)
```

Regards.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I am not looking to reverse the order of the table, I am looking to get it to display the last page of the table every time it refreshes.